# Why does a new Lotus Notes db built from a template require login credentials for browser users?

Tags: lotus-notes, acl

I created a new blank database and set it to inherit the design from a template.  Once the design was replaced, all looked good until I tried to open a form.  The server required login credentials.  The ACL is the same as other dbs that use this template so I do not know what I missed.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: I assume you are working with your database via browser. Am I right? The second point, are you sure that all *roles* which exist in another databases are exist in your new database and are set properly to the current user, who are going to open this form in the browser.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? That anonymous had access to open the form? Check your ACL - and add it to the question. As @RafaelOsipov is asking: is the form accessed from a browser?

Comment: Yes, the form is access via the browser. ...The question has actually  been answered.  In the form properties on the security tab I unchecked "All readers and above" on both "Default read access for documents created with this form" and Who can create documents with this form"...  I did not expect that to work because I am new to security on forms. I thought replacing the design would completely mimic the original (ACL and all!)  Thank you Rafael Osipov and Per Henrik Lausten!